# Failure web site service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

My web site done in asp.net c# VS2010 wanting to run from me indicates the following exception:

```
> The type initializer for 'PmServiceLayer.PmService' threw an exception.
```

In View Detail:

```
> {ExceptionDetail, probablemente creado por IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, cuyo valor es:
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'PmServiceLayer.PmService' threw an exception. ----> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at PmServiceLayer.PmService..cctor()
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila ExceptionDetail interna ---
   at PmServiceLayer.PmService..ctor()
   at CreatePmServiceLayer.PmService()
   at System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext.GetServiceInstance(Message message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InstanceBehavior.EnsureServiceInstance(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)}
> 
> 
Server stack trace: 
   en System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   en System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   en System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   en System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   en System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
> 
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     en
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
> reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    en
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
> msgData, Int32 type)    en
> PmPresentationLayer.WcfPmService.IpmContract.VoidInternalBatches()   
> en
> PmPresentationLayer.WcfPmService.IpmContractClient.VoidInternalBatches()
> en C:\Users\maquino.CPM\Desktop\Intranet\PmPresentationLayer\Service
> References\WcfPmService\Reference.cs:línea 742    en
> PmPresentationLayer.PmAgent.VoidInternalBatches() en
> C:\Users\maquino.CPM\Desktop\Intranet\PmPresentationLayer\Code\PmAgent.cs:línea
> 284    en PmPresentationLayer.SiteMaster.Page_Load(Object sender,
> EventArgs e) en
> C:\Users\maquino.CPM\Desktop\Intranet\PmPresentationLayer\Site.Master.cs:línea
> 25    en
> System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
> EventArgs e)    en System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    en
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    en
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    en
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    en
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

That suggests to me VoidInternalBatches:

```
public void VoidInternalBatches()
    {
        _wcfContractClient = WCFServiceClientSingleton.GetInstance();
        _wcfContractClient.VoidInternalBatches();
    }
```

from the browser brand me the following exception:

```
> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'.
The type initializer for 'PmServiceLayer.PmService' threw an exception.
Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.
> 
> Detalles de la excepción:
> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail,
> System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]: The type initializer for
> 'PmServiceLayer.PmService' threw an exception.

> 
> Error de código fuente:
> 
> 
> Línea 740:         Línea 741:        public void VoidInternalBatches()
> { Línea 742:            base.Channel.VoidInternalBatches(); Línea 743:
> } Línea 744:        
> 
> 
> Archivo de origen:
> C:\Users\maquino.CPM\Desktop\Intranet\PmPresentationLayer\Service
> References\WcfPmService\Reference.cs    Línea: 742
> 
> Seguimiento de la pila:
> 
> 
> [FaultException`1: The type initializer for 'PmServiceLayer.PmService'
> threw an exception.]   
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
> reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +10818447   
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
> msgData, Int32 type) +336   
> PmPresentationLayer.WcfPmService.IpmContract.VoidInternalBatches() +0 
> PmPresentationLayer.WcfPmService.IpmContractClient.VoidInternalBatches()
> in C:\Users\maquino.CPM\Desktop\Intranet\PmPresentationLayer\Service
> References\WcfPmService\Reference.cs:742   
> PmPresentationLayer.PmAgent.VoidInternalBatches() in
> C:\Users\maquino.CPM\Desktop\Intranet\PmPresentationLayer\Code\PmAgent.cs:284
> PmPresentationLayer.SiteMaster.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
> in
> C:\Users\maquino.CPM\Desktop\Intranet\PmPresentationLayer\Site.Master.cs:25
> System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
> EventArgs e) +51    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92   
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54   
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145   
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145   
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> +772
> 
> 
> Información de versión: Versión de Microsoft .NET Framework:4.0.30319;
> Versión ASP.NET:4.0.30319.34249
```

Error checking lines:

Site.Master.cs:25

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PmAgent _agent = new PmAgent();
            _agent.VoidInternalBatches();
        }
```

PmAgent.cs:284

```
public void VoidInternalBatches()
        {
            _wcfContractClient = WCFServiceClientSingleton.GetInstance();
            _wcfContractClient.VoidInternalBatches();
        }
```

Reference.cs:742

```
public void VoidInternalBatches() {
            base.Channel.VoidInternalBatches();
        }
```

I get the following code to the service

code webservice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="System.Configuration.IgnoreSectionHandler" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="appName" value="cpmapp" />
    <add key="appPassword" value="appuser.123" />
  </appSettings>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="c:\log\Log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] ID=%property{EventID} - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <!-- Define some output appenders -->
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] ID=%property{EventID} - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <!-- Setup the root category, add the appenders and set the default level -->
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="basicBh" name="PmServiceLayer.PmService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="usernameHttp" contract="PmContractLayer.IpmContract" />
      </service>
      <service name="PmServiceLayer.WebService" behaviorConfiguration="WebBh">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="AjaxBehavior" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="PmContractLayer.IwebContract" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="basicBh">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Windows" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="WebBh">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Windows" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webBinding" maxBufferSize="520000" maxReceivedMessageSize="520000">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="usernameHttp" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="520000" maxReceivedMessageSize="520000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="520000" maxStringContentLength="520000" maxArrayLength="520000" maxBytesPerRead="520000" maxNameTableCharCount="520000" />
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I apologize for the language, I'm from Argentina and even I have trouble handling the language.

I appreciate the help you can give me and of course the time spent on reading my query.

Greetings and good morning!

Answer (score 0):

Your project is not finding version 1.2.10 of **log4net**. You have several options to fix this:

1. Put the correct version assembly (log4net 1.2.10) in the place where it is referencing from.
2. Use NuGet and specify your assembly in packages.config.
3. Upgrade to the latest version of log4net (1.2.13).
4. Force the installation of log4net from the NuGet Console: `update-package -reinstall log4net.`
5. If desperate, edit the project file (.csproj) and search for a line like this:`Reference Include="log4net", Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral ..."` there you can check version and location of referenced assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following: PM> update-package -reinstall log4net
Update-Package : Unable to find package 'log4net'.
At line:1 char:15
+ update-package <<<<  -reinstall log4net
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.UpdatePackageCommand

PM> Install-Package log4net
Installing 'log4net 2.0.3'.
Successfully installed 'log4net 2.0.3'.
Adding 'log4net 2.0.3' to PmPresentationLayer.
Successfully added 'log4net 2.0.3' to PmPresentationLayer. Also remove the log4net project, but I presented the same mistake.